# Why is my MySqlCommand not actually updating my table?

Tags: c#, mysql, mono, connector-net

I have the following code in Mono, using the MySQL Connector/Net:

```
try
{
    MatchPersonResult mpr = personServ.MatchPerson(p, "MatchAndStore", null);
    using(MySqlCommand successcmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        successcmd.CommandText = "UPDATE myccontacts SET mcid = @mcid, matchresult = @mr, datetimematched = @dtm WHERE id = @id";
        successcmd.Connection = conn;
        successcmd.Parameters.Add("@mcid", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = int.Parse(mpr.PersonID);
        successcmd.Parameters.Add("@mr", MySqlDbType.Enum).Value = mpr.MatchResultStatus;
        successcmd.Parameters.Add("@dtm", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
        successcmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = person["id"];
        successcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine(mpr.PersonID);
    }
}
```

When the query is executed, the table isn't actually updated with anything.  I set a breakpoint on the Console.WriteLine call so I can check what's happening and when it's hit, I load the row with the id mentioned in the code and it has not been updated.  Even if I don't debug but just let the code execute, I see that nothing is happening to the database.  For clarity's sake - personServ.MatchPerson is actually a web reference imported into my solution, so I can check on the other end and do in fact see that the proper data were sent over and that the db update should take place.

Anyone know what to do?

TIA,
Benjy

P.S.: Everything *except* for the db updates is working - the catch block here (not posted for brevity's sake) is never hit.

Comment: what happens when you execute "select * from myccontacts where id = @id" before and after? Can you post the results? Also do you mean `mycontacts` rather than `myccontacts`?

Comment: Where is `person["id"];`? Should it be `Convert.ToInt32(person["id"]);`?

Comment: I'm actually doing a select along those lines before this try block is hit and it does in fact work (it's how the p object in the web service call is populated).  Selecting afterwards reveals that the update does not appear to be happening.  And no, the table name is correct but thanks for checking!

Comment: @jams - sorry about that.  `person` is the name of the datarow in the foreach loop that encloses this try.  And even with explicitly converting the value to an int it still does not work - just checked.

Comment: where you open the connection?

Comment: It's in a `using()` block that encloses the entire routine.

Comment: Nitpick: Does your dtm parameter need to be a string rather than just setting the value to `DateTime.Now`?  If so, easier to understand as `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")`.

Comment: @ChrisShaffer - super-awesome pointer, thanks.  Updating.

Comment: Can you view the MySQL General Query Log to see what mysql thinks is happening? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Comment: Try to print the return value from ExecuteNonQuery, it should return the number of affected rows. If it's 1, you know it's likely not a problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Could u try this code ?

```
 try
    {
        MatchPersonResult mpr = personServ.MatchPerson(p, "MatchAndStore", null);
        using(MySqlCommand successcmd = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            successcmd.CommandText = "UPDATE myccontacts SET mcid = @mcid, matchresult = @mr, datetimematched = @dtm WHERE id = id";
            successcmd.Connection = conn;
            successcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcid",int.Parse(mpr.PersonID));
            successcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mr",(int)mpr.MatchResultStatus);
            successcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtm", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
            successcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",Convert.Int32(person["id"]); 
            successcmd.Connection.Open();
            successcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            successcmd.Connection.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(mpr.PersonID);
        }
    }
```